# How to know what exceptions AWS APIs throws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

According to this page in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/quick-start.html#error-handling) you use exceptions in the new AWS API to understand when errors have occurred; they, in fact, even show an example with the `createBucket` function, however, when looking in the [API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_createBucket) it makes no reference about exactly what exceptions it can throw.

Is there a well documented way to find out?

Comment: This seems to be the Exception socumentation `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/namespace-Aws.StorageGateway.Exception.html`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah I mean this is the one for S3: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/namespace-Aws.S3.Exception.html but I really don't wanna add a check for all those exceptions into my code. I would pefer a method by method basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to post this on Github: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/111

Got the response that I should check for the basic `S3Exception` for all S3 calls.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for thrown exception type by functions, You juste have to look on the the documentation by functions, for instance the function **createPresignedUrl** throws [Aws\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_createPresignedUrl). Note some function throws no exceptions.

All exceptions are classes, when you throwing an exception you're using the "new" keyword. To build custom Exception you need to [Extend](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) them from the main Exception ! What that means ?

You just don't have to worry, and do this way.

**Global Exception caught**

```
try
{
    # code here
}

# if the exception type is match, script going inside this part.
catch (BucketAlreadyExistsException $e) 
{
    echo 'That bucket already exists! ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

# Catching many type you want.
catch (OverflowException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage . " - " . $e->getCode();
}

# Like a else, this part is catching all unhandled exception types.
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage . " - " . $e->getCode();
}

# if you're using php 5, you can also use finally instruction
finally
{

}
```

You can find few intrusting lines about exceptions on PHP [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), and you should also look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php) for the default php Exception types.

Comment: You see some exceptions I do actually want to catch in separate catch statements to create custom error handling so just feeding them all through that one function isn't good plus if I wanted to create custom handling for certain errors how do I know which errors I wish to create handling for if there is no real documentation about which functions throw which exceptions?

Comment: What I mean is: is there a place that describes what each function throws?

Comment: That is also not what I mean. If you look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_createBucket there is a section for everything except `throws` despite the fact that the function *can* throw exceptions. What I am looking for is the missing documentation

Comment: You juste have to look on the functions, for instance the function createPresignedUrl throws Aws\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException, i have edited my answer.

Comment: Yes it does have the documentation of what it throws there but not under the function edition of createBucket if you notice, I think this is a bug in their documentation